# Adding to AtomicInteger within ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

I have the following defined

```
private ConcurrentMap<Integer, AtomicInteger>  = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, AtomicInteger>();

private void add() {
  staffValues.replace(100, staffValues.get(100), new AtomicInteger(staffValues.get(100).addAndGet(200)));
}
```

After testing, the values I am getting are not expected, and I think there is a race condition here. Does anyone know if this would be considered threadsafe by wrapping the get call in the replace function?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Adding `250` to the value of key `100`?

Comment: @Bubbletan yes precisely, but it needs to be done in a thread safe manner, hence the use of AtomicInteger

Comment: If the keys of the map are never changed, you can use `Map<Integer, AtomicInteger>` and just call `map.get(100).addAndGet(250)`.

Answer (score 4):

A good way to handle situations like this is using the `computeIfAbsent` method (not the `compute` method that @the8472 recommends)

The [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) accepts 2 arguments, the key, and a `Function<K, V>` that will only be called if the existing value is missing. Since a AtomicInteger is thread safe to increment from multiple threads, you can use it easely in the following manner:

```
staffValues.computeIfAbsent(100, k -> new AtomicInteger(0)).addAndGet(200);
```

Comment: Note that in the OP's code, `staffValues.computeIfAbsent(100, k -> new AtomicInteger(0))` can be expressed more simply as `staffValues.get()`, since this entry is known to already be set.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues with your code. The biggest is that you're ignoring the return-value of `ConcurrentHashMap.replace`: if the replacement doesn't happen (due to another thread having made a replacement in parallel), you simply proceed *as if* it happened. This is the main reason you're getting wrong results.

I also think it's a design mistake to mutate an `AtomicInteger` and then immediately replace it with a different `AtomicInteger`; even if you can get this working, there's simply no reason for it.

Lastly, I don't think you should call `staffValues.get(100)` twice. I don't think that causes a bug in the current code — your correctness depends only on the second call returning a "newer" result than the first, which I think *is* actually guaranteed by `ConcurrentHashMap` — but it's fragile and subtle and confusing. In general, when you call `ConcurrentHashMap.replace`, its third argument should be something you computed using the second.

Overall, you can simplify your code either by not using `AtomicInteger`:

```
private ConcurrentMap<Integer, Integer> staffValues = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

private void add() {
    final Integer prevValue = staffValues.get(100);
    staffValues.replace(100, prevValue, prevValue + 200);
}
```

or by not using `replace` (and perhaps not even `ConcurrentMap`, depending how else you're touching this map):

```
private Map<Integer, AtomicInteger> staffValues = new HashMap<>();

private void add() {
    staffValues.get(100).addAndGet(200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `replace()`. AtomicInteger is a mutable value that does not need to be substituted whenever you want to increment it. In fact `addAndGet` already increments it in place.

Instead use `compute` to put a default value (presumably 0) into the map when none is present and otherwise get the pre-existing value and increment that.

If, on the other hand, you want to use immutable values put `Integer` instances instead of `AtomicInteger` into the map and update them with the atomic compute/replace/merge operations.

Comment: But does doing staffValues.get(100).addAndGet(...) not cause a race condition? As the get() operation is not threadsafe?

Comment: how does that relate to my answer?

Comment: Oh sorry, I got confused. I am unable to use JDK 1.8 however, so doing compute will not work.